# How can I prevent MySQL from caching variable values between Stored Procedure calls?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am experiencing some odd behavior where a stored procedure seems to be caching variable values or the output of a stored procedure between calls.  Here's a scenario:

## Table foo

```
id INT(10);
name VARCHAR2(100);
```

Has one row, with id=5 and name="a_valid_value"

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE fooProc()
BEGIN
      DECLARE testVar INT;
      SELECT id into @testVar FROM foo WHERE name = 'a_valid_value';
      SELECT @testVar as "testVar";
END;
$$
delimiter ;

CALL fooProc(); -- Outputs 5 as expected

DROP PROCEDURE fooProc;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE fooProc()
BEGIN
      DECLARE testVar INT;
      SELECT id into @testVar FROM foo WHERE name = 'NONEXISTENT_VALUE';
      SELECT @testVar as "testVar";
END;
$$
delimiter ;

CALL fooProc(); -- Outputs 5!
```

It doesn't matter that I changed the stored procedure body -- it still caches the value 5 in the var `testVar`.  The only way to get the value to correct itself is to disconnect and then reconnect.  Then when I call the second version of the stored procedure it returns an empty value as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@` are *user* variables, which are session specific.  You want to use local variables which should not have the `@` prefix.  Remove it from the stored procedure declarations.